# How to export two or more functions to the global context with the webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-4

I need to export two functions in the global scope, for example, I have these two functions:

```
function Suite() {//...} 

function Test() {//...}
```

I want to be able to export them to the global scope using the Webpack, so I can use them like this:

```
Suite();
Test();
```

instead of how I am now:

```
myLib.Suite();
myLib.Test();
```

I know I can export a function to the global scope like this:

```
module.exports = Suite;
```

But I do not know how it would do to export two or more functions to the global scope. For it to work on both nodejs and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your module you can use `global` as follows

```js
function Suite() {//...} 
function Test() {//...} 

global.Suite = Suite;
global.Test = Test;
```

`global` is `window` in the browser, and `global` in node when using webpack.

Comment: I found that using global would only be for nodejs, thank you.